# cancel last updation made in the database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, vb.net, winforms

I have one master table and a detailed table associated with it by referencing a `master_gid`, i have to insert the summary in master table and details in detailed table. everything works fine. am following the scenario :

1. insert master table
2. if master table insertion success then insert detailed table
3. if detailed table insertion failed the delete reference field from the master

every thing work fine for this time.

In the case of **updation** *i follows the same scenario*, but facing a problem in the case of detailed table insertion failure. How can i  `undo`(**using query**) the last updation in the master table in case detail_table insertion fails.
am using `Imports System.Data.Odbc` for the connect to the `mysql`

Comment: If you are using `ado.net` then you can use `Transaction` of `Command Class`.

Comment: see updation: am using `Imports System.Data.Odbc`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from msdn about [using transaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w47683ks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

```
Public Sub ExecuteTransaction(ByVal connectionString As String)

Using connection As New OdbcConnection(connectionString)
    Dim command As New OdbcCommand()
    Dim transaction As OdbcTransaction

    ' Set the Connection to the new OdbcConnection.
    command.Connection = connection

    ' Open the connection and execute the transaction. 
    Try
        connection.Open()

        ' Start a local transaction.
        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction()

        ' Assign transaction object for a pending local transaction.
        command.Connection = connection
        command.Transaction = transaction

        ' Execute the commands.
        command.CommandText = _
            "Insert into Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) VALUES (100, 'Description')"
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        command.CommandText = _
            "Insert into Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) VALUES (101, 'Description')"
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()

        ' Commit the transaction.
        transaction.Commit()
        Console.WriteLine("Both records are written to database.")

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        ' Try to rollback the transaction 
        Try
            transaction.Rollback()

        Catch 
            ' Do nothing here; transaction is not active. 
        End Try 
    End Try 
    ' The connection is automatically closed when the 
    ' code exits the Using block. 
End Using
```

End Sub